# How to use DispatcherServlet in tomcat with multiple servlets

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

I am working with a tomcat app with multiple servlets. 
I want to be able to initialize these and do dependency injection on server start up. 
I understand that I will have to declare a `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` .
But I am not sure how should my `web.xml` look like. Currently it looks like following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddAccount</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.addressbook.servlets.AddAccount</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddAccount</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddAccount</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.addressbook.servlets.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Currently, any request to add an account is sent directly to `/AddAccount` and for login the request is sent to `/Login`.

With `DispatcherServler`, how should my new `web.xml` and request structure look like? Do I have to make a new servlet that implements `DispatcherServlet` and forward each request to this new servlet which then forwards to correct Servlet?

Comment: Please don't learn Spring MVC this way. Read a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm) or 10.

Comment: Spring MVC is extremely powerful, but there is absolutely no way that you will get things done correctly without checking out multiple tutorial **before** starting experimenting around

Answer (score 0):

You dont need multiple servlets for several kind of actions in your app. The DispatcherServlet is a front controller that handles all requests and dispatches them to your controllers. As Sotirios suggested, have a look at the [Spring MVC manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet) first. Only the Dispatcher servlet is neccessary.